# serialport.js undefined ansi stream

Tags: javascript, serial-port

I'm trying to use `serialport.js`, even just including it at the moment causes a runtime error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'stream._ansicursor')`.

```
var React = require('react')
var SerialPort = require('serial port')
```

The context of this is within a `react` app, so its being compiled from `jsx`. I have no idea what or how this error came about, looking in at the line given in the error its coming from this code thats coming from serial port.js.

```
    /**
     * Creates a Cursor instance based off the given `writable stream` instance.
     */

    function ansi (stream, options) {
        if (stream._ansicursor) {
            return stream._ansicursor
        } else {
            return stream._ansicursor = new Cursor(stream, options)
        }
    }
    module.exports = exports = ansi
```

Comment: What context is this running in? React runs in the browser. I'm not familiar with serialport.js but it would make no sense that running in the browser. Are you making a webapp?

Comment: yeah in a browser, can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialport package you are trying to use operates on nodejs streams, this means it will need to run on the server within the nodejs context.

Depending on what you're trying to do with the serial port package, if you want to continue to have a React based web UI for this task, you will need to separate out the serialport actions and write an API using a nodejs framework. I'd suggest something like ExpressJS.

This way you can send requests to API urls that will perform the serialport tasks on the server and return JSON feedback that your web application, written in React, can interact with.